# exclude get_search_form from head of a certain page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I received this request from my client:

> *"We are still experiencing LOTS of problems with state aid recipients trying to log into their state aid account through the “My Account” function, even though you added language to direct them elsewhere.   To solve this problem, would it be possible to remove the “Student Disability”, “Contact Us”, and “My account” links from the top of the State Aid pages? "*

In researching and found that those links are generated in the `searchform.php` file of my theme.

How do I exclude that page from applying the `get_search_form()` function in the  `head.php`? This is what the navigation looks like with that function:

```
<div id="top-navigation">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

This is the site: http://Riseupms.com/state-aid/

Is it possible?

Comment: You could make a child theme and remove it there, or do a jQuery/javascript to just hide it from view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Page name of that particular page is "STATE FINANCIAL AID" you can do it like this

```
<?php if(!is_page( 'STATE FINANCIAL AID' ) { ?>
<div id="top-navigation">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

or you can exclude it by page id like this

```
<?php if(!is_page( 2341 ) { ?>
<div id="top-navigation">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

or u can simply do it with css

```
body.page.page-id-2341 #nav-bar li#item1,
body.page.page-id-2341 #nav-bar li#item2,
body.page.page-id-2341 #nav-bar li#item3 {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Oh jeez yeah, I don't know why I never thought about just simple css, no need for heavy handed JavaScript! You don't need to really do anything else.

Comment: The CSS idea worked simplest.  Here is what worked: '.page-id-2341 #item1,
.page-id-2341 #item2,
.page-id-2341 #item3 {
display:none;
}'

Comment: Thank you both for the effort!!

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark this as the correct answer if this helped to solve your problem. Thanks